# Best way to have an order sheet for every day

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to organize a spreadsheet to have one tab for today and one tab for each of the next 6 days on a rolling basis.

The tabs would pull order info from another sheet which has all aggregated order dated. Ie March 17's sheet would list all orders for that date, pulling from the aggregated order tab.

Is there a good way to set this up? The issue is I can't simply use =today on tab 1, =today+1 on tab 2, etc. because it needs to preserve manually added data as well formulas.
For example, col A is order number, col B is Items, col C is 'picked (y/n)', col d is notes. Col A and B pull from the aggregated sheet and will therefore move as the date changes but C and D are manually entered on that sheet so as the date changes they won't move with it.

Perhaps this is impossible on Google sheets and there is a more suitable, simple to use product you can recommend?

EDIT: I've made a sample workbook here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mN5XbyB4xV9WUDwZedcReoA_9VFQ0N-7VrI-gzw6WZQ/edit?usp=sharing

Columns A and B move as the date changed as desired. I want to find a way to have the info entered in Col C and D move along with it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dynamically name your sheets without using scripts that would automatically rename it for you. But with sheetnames you would have to rename all the formulas as well.
In my opinion it's not a good approach.

You can name your sheets +1 day, +2 days, +3 days, etc. and display dynamically data there according to actual date.

But anyway you would have to edit all the necessary data in your master sheet and only filter it for different sheets.

It all depends on the number of orders.

Comment: Thank you! I am less concerned about naming the sheets. The issue is more moving the data. I made a sample sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mN5XbyB4xV9WUDwZedcReoA_9VFQ0N-7VrI-gzw6WZQ/edit?usp=sharing

See how column A and B will move as the date changes which is good. Column C and D will not move. I'm trying to figure out a way to get them to move along with the order data.